# Plain Flask server vs UWSGI based server on K8s for production?

Tags: flask, kubernetes, uwsgi

I have a Flask app (that talks to a PostgreSQL DB via SQLAlchemy), that needs to be dockerized and deployed to production on a K8s cluster.

However, there are 2 options to achieve this:

1) Directly running the Flask app inside the containers with threaded mode enabled (This seems to be reasonably working fine)
2) Putting the Flask app behind a UWSGI app server and nginx as a reverse proxy.

Is there any reason as to why either of them are OK / not OK for deploying the app on production, given the K8s horizontal pod autoscaler can be leveraged to for scaling up if required.

NB: I am expecting a load of atleast 10-15 requests per second on the app.

Comment: I would recommend use flask+gevent+gunicorn+docker to deploy on kubernetes . You can scale application as much . Yes you need to define worker to setup gunicorn in production for concurrency . for 10-15 requests i would recommend 5 workers for flask .you can follow this ship application in docker . https://github.com/Anishmourya/flask-prometheus-gunicorn-docker-real-app

Comment: Yes, makes sense.. Thanks.

Comment: can you mark this question as done so i can get points ?thanks